# How does proper use of session.use_only_cookies and session_regenerate_id() cause personal DoS?

Tags: php, cookies, session-management, denial-of-service, session-fixation

From [PHP Session Management basics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php):

> Proper use of `session.use_only_cookies` and `session_regenerate_id()` can
> cause personal DoS with undeletable cookies set by attackers. In this
> case, developers may invite users to remove cookies and advise them
> they may be affected by a security issue. Attackers may set malicious
> cookies via a vulnerable web application, an exposed/vicious browser
> plugin, a physically compromised device, etc.

To put it in context:

In PHP, for security reasons, one usually set `session.use_only_cookies` to be true, which means the sessions are implemented via cookies, and use `session_regenerate_id()`, which means a new session ID is created every time a user authenticates to the website. `session_regenerate_id()` does not delete the old session ID/data.

I do not understand how a proper use of `session.use_only_cookies` and `session_regenerate_id()` can cause a "personal DoS". Could someone elaborate on this?